# Tensorflow: "staggered" sequence mask from indices?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Input like:

`[1, 3, 2]`

Desired output like (in a proper tensor):

```
[1 0 0 
 0 1 0
 0 1 0
 0 1 0
 0 0 1
 0 0 1]
```

I.e., very similar to tf.sequence_mask (which would give something like:

```
[1 1 1
 0 1 1
 0 1 0]
```

), but each subsequent element is "staggered" to start after the the prior sequence mask finishes.

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done by taking a square identity matrix of size equal to the number of elements in your input and then by applying `tf.tile()` `inputs[i]` number of times for each row `i` in the identity matrix:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.constant([1, 3, 2])

unit = tf.eye(num_rows=inputs.get_shape().as_list()[0])
unstacked = tf.unstack(unit)
tiled = [tf.tile(u[None, ...], multiples=[inputs[i], 1])
         for i, u in enumerate(unstacked)]
res = tf.concat(tiled, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(res))
# [[1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very speedy response!  This is perfect.

Comment: Great, glad it helped!